# What is the mechanism of synthesizing hydroxybenzotriazole?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, synthesis

I have big problem with this reaction.

[image]

Is this nucleophilic substitution? Cl is removed by hydrazine? It's my only idea, I don't know if this mechanism below is correct for this example:
[image]

Comment: This is a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/141/7448) question. We have a policy which states that ‎you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the problem. It'll make us certain that ‎we aren't doing your homework for you. Otherwise, this question may get closed.‎ Please [edit] in your full reasoning or thoughts on this.

Comment: related http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/23482/benzotriazole-to-o-phenylenediamine

Comment: It looks pretty reasonable to me. I'm not positive, but I like it.

Comment: The second picture presents mechanism of o-nitrophenylohydrazine with KOH/H2O....so my reaction would have the same mechanism?

Comment: Yes it looks plausible except two things 1) Your conditions above don't have base present. 2) In the top-right corner of the second picture I would have an intermolecular proton transfer instead of a 4-membered intramolecular transition state.

Comment: So what it looks like, when I'm using EtOH and hydrazine? I must do it on laboratory...

Comment: Given that you've shown *my* proposed mechanism, yes, I think that's correct. http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/26770/amine-addition-to-nitro-group/26880#26880